# How to reference the value of a React component

Tags: reactjs

I want to call a React component like this:

```
class States extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(
      <Catalog>Estados</Catalog>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the declaration of the component:

```
class Catalog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Crud>{this.title}</Crud>
    )
  }
}
```

I thought that `{this.title}` would convey the string `Estados`, but I get nothin on the screen.

Where is the title of the component stored in the declaration of it?

Comment: You can get Estados in children e.g {this.props.children}

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to reference `this.props.children` to access the children of the component.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html
Your Catalog component should look like this.

```
class Catalog extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Crud>{this.props.children}</Crud>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope that helps! :)